# On the multi-dimensional inputs to the Keras Dense layers and the concept of the batches for them

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Assuming a Dense layer (in Keras) is fed by an input tensor with a shape of `(batch_size, a1, a2)`. Based on my understanding, the neuron units of the Dense layer are only connected to the elements of the last axis (`a2`). Thus, it is correct to say that Keras assumes the first axis is `batch_size` while in practice, the weights are shared between `batch_size * a1` things (all with `a2` weighted features). In other words, it really does not matter you input the Dense layer with a tensor of the shape `(batch_size, a1, a2)` or `(batch_size * a1, a2)`. Of course, the shape of the output for the latter case is different, but we can again reshape it to get the same results.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, it is indeed correct, the non linear transformation will be applied to every instance of the last axis, so all the previous axis are irrelevant